# OpenCV + GPU error

Tags: c++, opencv, gpu

I am just starting with OpenCV programming.

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKNGH58tcYA) tutorial. I tried the drawing sample (available in opencv samples' folder) and it runs alright.

The problem is when I try to run something on gpu, like the code on the bottom of [this](http://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html) page. The message I get is:

[image]

I am using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013 (selected opencv/build/x64/vc12 folder), cmake 3.7.0, opencv 2.4.13 and nvidia geforce gtx 980 (before installing opencv I installed cuda toolkit 8).

Someone knows what may be causing this error?

Comment: Did you build OpenCV with CUDA support? You may have to explicitly enable it in CMake when configuring the build.

Comment: well, OpenCV seems not to know that...

Comment: Any ideia about how to solve that?

Comment: I can't really be precise about the details, because my OpenCV version is 3.x and everything works (although with slightly different syntax), but can you at least call `cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()`? If you can, what does it return? Do you have some CUDA dll-s in your binary folder, e. g. `opencv_cudasomething.dll`? Did you check the release notes for OpenCV 2.4.13 to see if it supports CUDA 8.0?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. `cv::gpu::getCudaEnabledDeviceCount()` returns 0. I'm kind of newbie, I'm not the directory where dll-s are supposed to be. I checked the _build/x64/vc12/_ folder of OpenCV. There is none dll with `opencv_cudasomething.dll`. There is one `opencv_gpu2413`. About the release notes, I didn't found any thing about versions of Cuda in the release 2.4.12, but in version 2.2 it says "_you need to have the latest NVidia CUDA SDK installed_"

Comment: This question is quite dated, but they say there OpenCV 2.3 and 2.3.1 only supports CUDA 4.0, which was not the latest version at the time: stackoverflow.com/questions/10243928/ There may be something like that with 2.4.x, no matter how many times they say you need the latest CUDA SDK. I actually tried building OpenCV 2.4.13 yesterday, with CUDA 8.0 and VS15 (that's the only one I have installed), builds without a problem (indeed, there is an `opencv_gpu` dll, guess they changed it to `opencv_cuda` in the 3.x branch), correctly reports the number of GPUs, but freezes with your example.